# How do I change the watermark colour in LibreOffice PDF exports?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm an avid LibreOffice user, and sometimes I use it to generate sensitive PDFs (meaning, for preview purposes; I'm a writer). Recently I tried the watermark feature for PDF exports, but it's an ugly green colour that makes reading very difficult.

Is there a way to change the colour of the watermark?

Comment: Umm, is this a special "Export PDF" feature? I couldn't find it in that menu. Or is this the general Page Background watermark?

Comment: Is your watermark only color, or it is a text watermark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that any of the answers currently address this question. This question is referring to the new options to export a pdf with a watermark.

> `File` --> `Export as PDF`

Under the `General` tab, see the `Watermark` section.

Check the box `Sign with Watermark` and enter watermark text.

Text appears in the pdf in bright green.

Its not currently possible to change this value as its hard-coded into a patch which changed the color from bright red. This means that you'd have to change the value in the source code to do anything. The change was made to make the document more readable, and because the color is in-line with the LibreOffice colors. The discussion on the LO maillist is available here:

- [Dev - [PATCH] Change of the color of the watermark at the pdfexport](http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/PATCH-Change-of-the-color-of-the-watermark-at-the-pdfexport-td2127124.html)

There is some talk there of addressing the issue, but i don't think anything has been done yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes but it's something of a hack.

First, create a graphic in the package of your choice ([Inkscape](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/inkscape) is a favourite of mine) for your watermark. This would be the word 'draft' for example. Make the page size of the graphic the same size and shape as the pages you're writing on in Libre Office and save it as a [png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). You can make it any shade or colour you like.

You can apply a background to any page by selecting `Format>Page>Background` and selecting graphic instead of colour. Set the background to take up the whole page area then browse to your png file.

You can create page styles that include any number of watermarks selecting the `styles and formatting` menu (<kbd>F11</kbd>) and going to page styles. Create a new page style and add your background using the process from the paragraph above. Save your new page style and you can apply it to any page you like. There's a screencast of this process on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXdxK9JCW6Q).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I can't accept this as the answer, but it's a good solution none the less.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather remarkable. However I would not export with watermark sign !!!
Create a text in Draw, you decide whatever it says, be it Draft, Samply, Copyright etc and your layout and textcolour etc.
Save it as .odg than use an online converter to make it a .png file.
This file you can use !! You just create a new Style in Libreoffice Writer and use the png file for the style.
Double click on the "new" style and you have your watermark. (This watermark remains even when the file is exported to PDF.)
For instructions I found the following video which helped me very much:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXdxK9JCW6Q

Hope this helps